# Change return-path of email message sent in linux + postfix

Tags: linux, command-line, email, smtp, postfix

I am trying to test DMARC settings in order to avoid [5322.From header spoofing attacks](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/eopfieldnotes/2015/12/23/troubleshooting-and-identifying-spoofing-attacks/) and I need a quick way to send messages using different From and Return-path addresses. I've tried:

```
mail -a "Return-Path: test@domaina.com" -a "Reply-To: test@domaina.com" \
 -a "From: test@domainb.com" me@target.com
```

This doesn't work (it uses the From: address for return-path).

I've also tried changing postfix smtp_generic_maps. This changes all the addresses.

Is there any simple way to do this from the command line without having to telnet to a MX and speak SMTP?

Simple perl or PHP script would be acceptable.